# Pytorch: Storage has wrong size while loading state_dict from GPU on CPU

Tags: pytorch, torch

I've trained a model on a GPU (server) and saved the state_dict. Now I want to do some tests locally on my CPU, so I downloaded the state_dict, create a model and want to load that state_dict. After some research, I found the map_location-attribute of the torch.load()-function. So finally I'm trying to load the state_dict in the following way:

```
device = torch.device('cpu')
model = BertForTokenClassification.from_pretrained('bert-base-uncased', num_labels=4)
model.load_state_dict(torch.load('state_dict.pth', map_location=device))
```

But I get the following RuntimeError:

```
RuntimeError: storage has wrong size: expected 1005829391 got 393216
```

Does anyone know, what to do for loading the state_dict on my CPU?

Comment: Are you sure the `model` is exactly the same?

Comment: In fact the trained model is a subclass of `BertForTokenClassification`. From your question, I can conclude, that this won't work?

Comment: I mean it need to have exactly the same parameters, same size, etc.